# Some questions about simplification of the equation with matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

I have such an equation $(X^{-1} \cdot 2 \cdot A)^{-1} - B = 4X
$
Where $B$ and $A$ are matrices.

So, I did such a simplification.

\begin{align}
& \frac 12 A^{-1}X - B = 4X\\
\iff & \frac 12 A^{-1} X = 4X + B\\
\iff & \frac 12 A^{-1} X - 4X = B\\
\iff & \left(\frac 12 A^{-1} - 4I\right)X = B\\
\iff & X = B \left(\frac 12 A^{-1} - 4I\right)^{-1}.
\end{align}

Am I right?

Comment: Everything was correct until the last step.  It should be
$$
X = (\frac 12 A^{-1} - 4I)^{-1}B
$$

Comment: It’s very important to remember that matrix multiplication is not commutative. The side on which you multiply matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really.

It is correct that $(X^{-1}\cdot2\cdot A)^{-1}=\frac{1}{2}A^{-1}X$, so the equation becomes
$$
\frac{1}{2}A^{-1}X-4X=B
$$
It's easier if you simplify it to $A^{-1}X-8IX=2B$, so
$$
(A^{-1}-8I)X=2B
$$
and therefore, multiplying by the inverse *on the left*,
$$
X=2(A^{-1}-8I)^{-1}B
$$
Your solution would be good as well, provided you keep the correct side of the multiplication.

In order to do those steps you need that $A$ is invertible and hasn't $1/8$ among its eigenvalues.